# sqlite3 Select with an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I want to make a select in iOS XCode with SQLite3 like this:

```c
//arraycat is the array from which the data comes...multiple selections of a tableview

pros = [arraycat componentsJoinedByString:@","];

const char *sqlselect = "SELECT DISTINCT zuser.zid, zuser.zplz,zuser.zort,zuser.zhofname,zuser.zstrassenr,zuser.zlatitude,zuser.zlongitude FROM zuser,zangebot,zkategorie WHERE zkategorie.zprodukt IN(?) and zangebot.zprodukte=1 and zkategorie.zuser_id=zuser.zid and zangebot.zuser_id=zuser.zid and zkategorie.zdelete_r=0 and zangebot.zdelete_r=0";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlselect, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    NSLog(@"abfrage select produkt hat nicht geklappt");
}

//here has to be the problem... 
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, [pros UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

If I just select one category on the tableview then it works, but if I select multiple and send them to this statement then it works not. Why this? When I write by hand the categories in the SQL Query `IN(?)` like `('Vegetable','fruits')` then it works too....why not with the `componentsJoinedByString` method?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a parameter is a placeholder [for a *single* value](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). When you bind a string to a parameter, that parameter's value is the contents of the string, regardless of what those contents are.
In other words, your query is probably equivalent with

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE produkt IN ('Vegetable,fruits')
```

If you want to compare against multiple strings, you have to create a query with multiple parameters:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE produkt IN (?,?)
```

and bind all of them separately:

```c
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, "Vegetable", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 2, "fruits", -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```